# vuejs : passing props down to a component in javascript?

Tags: vue.js

How can i pass down props to a javascript [Vue component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

this is how i normally do it.

```
<child prop="value"></value>
```

but i want to do it like this

```
var Child = Vue.extend({
    ...
});
Chid.passProps( {foo: 'bar'} ) // some thing like this?
```

is this possible in vue.js?

this is the full code:

```
var Child = Vue.extend({
    props: ['foo'],
    methods: {
        printIt: function() {
            console.log(this.foo)
        }
    },
    template: '#example'
});
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },
    render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement(Child); // pass down foo
    }
});
```

[link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dacoqa/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the section on render functions https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

Essentially you need to pass the props with the call to the render function as part of the data element

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        foo: 'bar'
    },
    render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement(Child, {
            props: {
                foo: this.foo
            }  
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved tons of time. Here is more information in official documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth